# HtmlDivElement has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to derive some identifying property from this element:

```
<div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
  <ul class="rtsUL">
    <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst rtsLast">
      <a class="rtsLink rtsSelected" href="#">
        <span class="rtsOut">
          <span class="rtsIn">
            <span class="rtsTxt">Dashboard</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

using this javascript:

```
function OnClientDragging(sender, eventArgs) {
    var target = eventArgs.get_htmlElement();
    console.log(target);
    var currentZone = TryGetZoneFromTarget(target);
}

function TryGetZoneFromTarget(target) {
//If the mouse moves too quickly target.id returns a red herring.
if (/\S/.test(target.id) == false) {
    if (target.indexOf("rtsLevel") != -1) {
        return null; //The tabstrip has an invisible div which doesn't have an ID, but isn't a redherring.
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

The div doesn't have an id specified, but I don't seem to be able to 'talk' to it at all, either. I've tried '.hasClass("rtsLevel")' and was being told hasClass not defined, so I tried to do a string comparison, but hit the same wall.

What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT: Solution was `if ( $(target).hasClass('rtsLevel') ) {`

Comment: What attribute on the div are you trying to look at?  className? id?  text content?  You have to address the appropriate attribute of the object, not just the object itself.

Comment: Try `if ( $( target ).hasClass( 'rtsLevel' ) ) { ...`

Comment: Silly question, but -- you made sure jQuery is actually loading? I ask because 'hasClass' is a jquery method.

Comment: I tried accessing target.className and was told it was undefined. I tried .hasClass and was told it didn't have the method. id is undefined because it doesn't have an id.

Comment: Sime Vidas was correct. His solution worked. @Sime, if you want to respond with that as an actual response I would accept it as answer. Thank you!

Comment: if you are going to run a jquery method on the dom element, the dom element needs to be part of a jquery object. `if ($(target).is(":has(.rtsLevel))")`

Comment: What is `eventArgs`? What is `eventArgs.get_htmlElement()`? Why do you think an HTML Element should have an `indexOf` method? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @Sean You can accept jfriend's answer, it's good...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `target` is a valid DOM element, then you should be able to do:

```
target.className.indexOf("rtsLevel") != -1
```

or if you're using jQuery and target is a DOM element, you can do:

```
$(target).hasClass("rtsLevel")
```

if `target.className` is undefined, then target is not a DOM element and that would be your problem.